# Message instance has no attribute 'read' in Google app engine mail receive

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

Code in receive handler

```
class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
   def receive(self, mail_message):
    logging.info("Received a message from: " + mail_message.sender)
    #logging.info("Received a message from: " + mail_message.attachments)
    logging.info("Received a message from: " + mail_message.date)
    logging.info("Received a message from: " + mail_message.subject)
    report = DocFile()
    report.doc_name = mail_message.subject
    if mail_message.attachments is not None:
        report.doc_file = mail_message.attachments
    else:
        report.doc_file = mail_message.bodies(content_type='text/plain')
    report.put()

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)        

def main():
run_wsgi_app(application)
if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

code in url.py

```
inbound_services:
- mail

handlers:
- url: /_ah/mail/.+ 
script: handle_incoming_email.py
```

error when i try to send a simple email from http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/inboundmail

```
Message send failure

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 509, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\mail_handlers.py", line 58, in post
    self.receive(mail.InboundEmailMessage(self.request.body))
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail.py", line 547, in __init__
    self.update_from_mime_message(mime_message)
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail.py", line 1081, in update_from_mime_message
    mime_message = _parse_mime_message(mime_message)
  File "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail.py", line 232, in _parse_mime_message
    return email.message_from_file(mime_message)
  File "F:\Python25\lib\email\__init__.py", line 66, in message_from_file
    return Parser(*args, **kws).parse(fp)
  File "F:\Python25\lib\email\parser.py", line 68, in parse
    data = fp.read(8192)
  AttributeError: Message instance has no attribute 'read'
```

EDIT
This error comes only on local machine and not on app engine

Comment: tried to indent, let me know if its better

Comment: No, the code you've posted is a syntax error, as is the yaml file.

Comment: Except the indents that are required by python, is there any other syntax error that you see. If you can ignore the indents and let me know why the error is coming than it will be very useful

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest version of the API? for the incoming mail function need to be the  1.2.6 or greatest.

Later i saw in google groups the "solution"  I quote Joshua Smith

### "I've found that you need to restart the local dev environment before

### doing any inbound mail testing.  Otherwise, you'll get that read error"

So every time that you change your code you **MUST** restart the server, even if only add white spaces (seriously)

Comment: yes , its the latest version and i have done multiple re-sstarts, it works alright in production

Comment: I test your code, and when i modify it the sources and the error appears, then when restart the server and works fine.

Comment: Thanx Kristian, I have also posted the same at http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/2b8b8f652fc3a98a/1e7ed89c158cdd75#1e7ed89c158cdd75 and the issue is observed by others too. Are you saying that you dont get read error when you restart server and you are able to obtain the email?

Comment: Yes, i write the code and i get the error, then i restart the server and works fine, but next i add a single withe space in the code and the error came again

Before
[IMG]http://i48.tinypic.com/i74yea.png[/IMG]
After
[IMG]http://i46.tinypic.com/2cqb12o.png[/IMG]

Comment: here's the pastebin from the code 
http://pastebin.com/m7dbbf8a2
and from the yaml file
http://pastebin.com/d6de03ba9